# Adding xy data and exporting layer in function using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, xy, function

I am trying to add xy data into the attribute tables of 2 point layers, then export the tables into 2 separate excel tables using this code:

```
env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr"
lyr1 = r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr\karka.shp"
lyr2 = r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr\gaskarka.shp"
arcpy.AddXY_management(lyr1)
arcpy.AddXY_management(lyr2)
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyr1,
                          r"G:\Users\yaron\Downloads\karka.xls")

arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyr2,
                          r"G:\Users\yaron\Downloads\gaskarka.xls")
```

This works just fine. But when I try to build a function in order to avoid this clumsy code, and get faster code- I get stuck:

```
def xy(lyr1,env):
    env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr"
    lyr1 = r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr\karka.shp"
    arcpy.AddXY_management(lyr1)
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyr1,
                          r"G:\Users\yaron\Downloads\karka.xls")
print xy(lyr1,env)
```

Comment: Do you want to call the function with path of lyr and env, for example `xy(r'C:\folder\shape.shp', r'C:\folder')`? Then dont assign them values inside the function.

Comment: yes BERA, but i want to do it at the same time for 2 layers

Comment: The purpose of the function is to be re-used. If you just want to apply the same action to iterable objects, a loop is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be any dynamic variable inside the function. First create the function with generic variables, and replace those variables with values when you call the function. And the `env` variable is not necessary here:

```
import arcpy, os

def xy(lyr):
    shp_name = os.path.split(lyr)[-1]
    xls_name = os.path.join(r"G:\Users\yaron\Downloads", shp_name.replace(".shp", ".xls"))
    arcpy.AddXY_management(lyr)
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyr, xls_name)


xy(r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr\karka.shp")
xy(r"G:\PROJECTS\osfie\gis\lyr\gaskarka.shp")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the function with path to shape and excelfile dont assign them values inside the function:

```
def xy(featureclasses, outfolder):
    import arcpy, os
    for fc in featureclasses:
        arcpy.AddXY_management(fc)
        arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc,os.path.join(outfolder,os.path.basename(fc).split('.')[0])+'.xls')

xy([r'C:\Default.gdb\Features_10000',r'C:\Folder\Features_20000.shp'], r'C:\Test')
```